# Adding a mousemove listener to the controls of a video element with Javascript

Tags: javascript, events, html5-video

basically I've got a basic video element

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
<source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Is there a non-jQuery way to add a listener to the controls of a video element? the controls, as you know, will look like this on different browsers:

[image]

All I need is a function to run once a user hover over that.

Edit: I also need a function that will run once a user moves out of the controls

Comment: There are plenty of custom html video players available which would allow the control you are looking for. Is that an option?

Comment: I can't use anything but pure javascript since it's an API. adding jQuery is impossible too since it's a big library and i dont wanna force it. basically, I need a light(100 lines max) javascript code.

Comment: I didn't mention Jquery, it can be easily done with Javascript. If you are okay with that I can provide you can example.

Comment: Please do, but not a custom html video player library, just the original.

Answer (score 0):

To add a **mouse over** event to an object, you can use the following code:

```
yourobject.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    //whatever you want to do
});
```

To add a **mouse out** event to an object, you can use the following code:

```
yourobject.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
    //whatever you want to do
});
```

---

References:

- [Mouseover Event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp)
- [Mouseout Event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseout.asp)

Comment: sounds promising, but how can I pin that event to the controls only? I know how to do a mouseover and mouseout event on a regular video element, but that is not helpfulh ere.

Comment: @user1938653 Then you need to add your own controls to the video.       I found good tutorials here: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/building-custom-controls-for-html5-videos and http://www.creativebloq.com/html5/build-custom-html5-video-player-9134473